# How can I enable auto create database in Teradata from LDAP?

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I am using Teradata Vantage 17.10 and successfully enabled the LDAP configuration. I create one user in Teradata identical to my LDAP user. I successfully managed to log in with this user if I shifted the mechanism to LDAP. So all the configuration is correct if I change the password of a user in LDAP it affects the Teradata as well. So all the new users created in LDAP have access to the Teradata viewpoint as well.

**What Problem do I face?**
Now the issue is when I create a new user in LDAP it is not able to log in with the Teradata database via TD-Studio. I have to manually create the same user in Teradata. I don't want to create all users manually. I want all the new users from LDAP created in the Teradata database as well.

I am looking for any idea or advice on how can I do it. Even the documentation link will be helpful I didn't manage to find this in the Documentation.
Thank you in Advance.

I try to create a profile add the user to the profile and also set a role. I try to use the TDNEGOCONF utility but this is not available in 17.10

**----------------------------   UPDATE --------------------------------**

When I follow the link provided in the command I have managed to do the following.
I create a user the same as ldap in Teradata.
I create an external role
I am not able to add a user for an external role as this error appears

```
Executed as Single statement.  Failed [5930 : HY000] External role 'ldapAdmin' may not be granted in the database. 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.377 
 
STATEMENT 1: GRANT  failed.
```

In [documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Security-Administration/July-2021/Using-Native-Directory-Schema-to-Provision-Directory-Users/Mapping-Additional-Directory-Users-to-Vantage-User-Role-and-Profile-Objects/Mapping-Directory-Users-to-Vantage-Profiles/Example-Mapped-Profiles) this is an example provided.

```
dn: cn=profile1,ou=profiles,cn=systemone,cn=tdat,dc=domain,dc=com
changeType: modify
add: member
member: uid=dirUser7,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com

dn: cn=profile2,ou=profiles,cn=systemone,cn=tdat,dc=domain,dc=com
changeType: modify
add: member
member: uid=dirUser3,ou=people,cn=domain,cn=com
```

The question is in which file I need to update these settings. There is no pat or file name mentioned in the documentation.

-----------------------------------UPDATE 2  --------------------------

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# usage: loadschema server
#

if [ $# != 1 ]; then
  echo "Wrong # args"
  echo "usage: $0 server"
  exit 1
fi

cd /opt/teradata/tdgss/etc
SNC=$(ldapsearch -H ldap://$1 -b "" -s base schemanamingcontext | \
     grep -i schemanamingcontext | \
     cut -d' ' -f2)
if [ "$SNC" = "" ]; then
  echo "Schema naming context not found on server $1"
  exit 1
fi

cat tdat.actdir.schema ipfilter.actdir.schema policy.actdir.schema | \
  sed -e "s/CN=Schema/$SNC/" | \
  ldapmodify -x -c -H ldap://$1 -D "cn=tauqer,dc=domain,dc=com" -W
```

I have removed -z as I am not using TSL and I don't have Kerberos either.

-----------------------UPDATE ------------------------
from the above script when I ass -b "OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=com the error went away and ldapmodify run but show this error Now
My username and Password is correct.

```
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "cn=tdatProfileMember,requesting:"
ldap_add: Invalid DN syntax (34)
        additional info: 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-03100231, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8350, best match of:
        'requesting:'


adding new entry "cn=tdatProfileMemberOf,requesting:"
ldap_add: Invalid DN syntax (34)
        additional info: 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-03100231, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8350, best match of:
        'requesting:'


adding new entry "cn=tdatRoleMember,requesting:"
ldap_add: Invalid DN syntax (34)
        additional info: 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-03100231, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8350, best match of:
        'requesting:'


adding new entry "cn=tdatRoleMemberOf,requesting:"
ldap_add: Invalid DN syntax (34)
        additional info: 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-03100231, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8350, best match of:
        'requesting:'


adding new entry "cn=tdatUserMember,requesting:"
ldap_add: Invalid DN syntax (34)
        additional info: 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-03100231, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8350, best match of:
        'requesting:'


adding new entry "cn=tdatUserMemberOf,requesting:"
ldap_add: Invalid DN syntax (34)
        additional info: 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-03100231, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8350, best match of:
        'requesting:'


modifying entry ""

adding new entry "cn=tdatGroupExt,requesting:"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AD, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

modifying entry ""

modifying entry "cn=Group,requesting:"
ldap_modify: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0910C0, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

modifying entry ""

adding new entry "cn=tdatUserExt,requesting:"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AD, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

modifying entry ""

modifying entry "cn=User,requesting:"
ldap_modify: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0910C0, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

modifying entry ""

adding new entry "cn=tdatRootNode,requesting:"
ldap_add: Invalid DN syntax (34)
        additional info: 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-03100231, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8350, best match of:
        'requesting:'


modifying entry ""

adding new entry "cn=tdatSystem,requesting:"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AD, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

modifying entry ""

adding new entry "cn=tdatContainer,requesting:"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AD, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

modifying entry ""

adding new entry "cn=tdatProfile,requesting:"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AD, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

adding new entry "cn=tdatUser,requesting:"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AD, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

adding new entry "cn=tdatRole,requesting:"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AD, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

modifying entry ""

modifying entry ""

adding new entry "cn=tdatPolicy,requesting:"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AD, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

modifying entry ""

adding new entry "cn=tdatPolicyContainer,requesting:"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AD, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

modifying entry ""

adding new entry "cn=tdatMechanism,requesting:"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AD, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

adding new entry "cn=tdatConfidentialityQoP,requesting:"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AD, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

adding new entry "cn=tdatIntegrityQoP,requesting:"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AD, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

adding new entry "cn=tdatOption,requesting:"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AD, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

adding new entry "cn=tdatInternalNetworkGroup,requesting:"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AD, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

adding new entry "cn=tdatExternalNetworkGroup,requesting:"
ldap_add: No such attribute (16)
        additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0911AD, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839

modifying entry ""
```

Comment: Link to 17.10 documentation https://docs.teradata.com/r/Security-Administration/July-2021/Creating-Users-and-Granting-Privileges/Working-with-Directory-Users/Auto-Provisioned-Directory-Users

Comment: Hi Fred, This auto provisioning not allow to create new database or User on the Teradata.  Is Teradata have this approach that we can auto- provision databases and users directly from LDAP? I have enabled the Auto-provision from Viewpoint and also in TdgssUserConfigFile.xml set yes. However my user is not able to login with LDAP mechanism in Teradata studio and in LDAP test it still show Authenticated but not authorized.  DO I need to install some TD utilities on LDAP or need to use any third party software's? Thank you for your support.

Comment: The directory must map the auto-provisioned user to a PROFILE and one or more EXTERNAL ROLE - see the Security Admin Guide as linked above. BTW - Viewpoint auto-provisioning applies only to the Viewpoint server itself.

Comment: Hi Fred, as per the documentation I created an external role and when I try to add a user with the role I see an error which I updated in the question. Also, the mapping part is very unclear. In which file do I need to update the information? Any path and file name, please. I am using vantage 17.10. It will be a great help if you provide detailed information.

Comment: The "mapping" must be stored in the _directory_ you are accessing via LDAP. You can't directly GRANT an EXTERNAL ROLE within the database. There are different "schema" approaches supported, e.g. is role membership just an attribute of the user, or is there a separate "role" object that has user names as attributes.

Comment: Hi Fred, Thanks for your help so far. I created a group in LDAP and added the user under that group. I also created same role in TD and give privileges'. I also test the LDAP config. SO far so good.  I also enable the AUTO Provisioning with dbscontrol write it check it again it is working. Still my new user is not able to connect with Teradata. DO I need to install  Schema Extensions ? Did I miss something ?

Comment: I see this error when I try to login new user with LDAP mechanism in Teradata studio  The UserId, Password or Account is invalid. Also, ldap search is successful.    # search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

Comment: There should be more information about the cause of the failure logged in /var/log/messages at OS level and/or dbc.Software_Event_LogV at database level.

Comment: Hi Fred, Can you please explain a bit how can I perform this https://docs.teradata.com/r/Security-Administration/July-2021/Provisioning-Directory-Users-with-Teradata-Schema-Extensions/Mapping-Directory-Users-to-Teradata-Vantage-Objects/Mapping-Directory-Users-to-Vantage-Users/Example-Mapping-a-Directory-User-to-a-tdatUser   ?   Where can I find the tdat User object and what is the path? Thanks

Comment: Back up to the prior topic, "Creating Containers and Inserting Objects" or even review the whole section "Provisioning Directory Users with Teradata Schema Extensions". An alternative is the following section "Using Native Directory Schema to Provision Directory Users"

Comment: Hi Fred, I am trying to install schema on my LDAP. I copy the script and create a new file in as loadschema under /opt/teradata/tdgss/bin dir. my script is under Update2 in Question. I run it as ./loadschema IP_LDAP and see error     SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
        additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (No Kerberos credentials available)
Schema naming context not found on server

Comment: my User and password are correct but when I run  ldapmodify -x -D 'cn=tauqer,ou=Users,ou=TDLDAP,dc=domain,dc=com' -W -H ldap://123.123.123.123 -f loadschema     I see error    invalid password.  However same username and password show successful test for LDAP config and Teradata studio connection.  Any advice please?

Comment: After adding -x in search now I see this    sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated `s' command
Enter LDAP Password:        After adding the LDAP password noting happen.

Comment: It appears that ldapsearch isn't finding the DN for schemaNamingContext but the error message returned includes keyword as part of the text, so grep / cut returned the word "requesting:" instead of the expected context name. Run the ldapsearch by itself and see if you can determine how to correctly set SNC value.

Comment: When I use LDAP search with IP and cn etc it returns the result from the LDAP server only dNSTombstoned: FALSE    rest all show. However when I try to run the loadschema
script it shows the error as above.

Comment: Hi Fred, When I run ./ldapsearch -x -h 123.123.123.111 -D "cn=tauqer,ou=Users,ou=TDLDAP,dc=testdomain,dc=com" -W "(objectClass=*)" schemanamingcontext      It return    search: 2
result: 32 No such object
text: 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310021F, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best
 match of:
        ''


# numResponses: 1
   What exactly is the issue here? Does my TD setup or LDAP have an issue?

Comment: Seems LDAP does. The script searches the directory base entries for the schemaNamingContext (to append to the distinguished names of the new Teradata schema container entries). It does not find that entry.

Comment: Hi Fred, Just a confirmation about the role mapping. I create active directory groups and provide privileges to each group e.g ldapAdmin has everything and ldapUser read-only. I also created the same role in Teradata.  How can I map these two? Like after creating an LDAP use in Teradata manually with a noPassword login grant. How would Teradata know about the privileges? Something is missing here. Can you please suggest any tutorial?

Comment: I'm not aware of any tutorial or documentation beyond the Security Administration manual. If you are using the Teradata schema extensions, there should be a tdatRole object with a cn that matches the External Role name in the database. That tdatRole object would have tdatRoleMember attributes each of which is the dn of a tdatUser object. If you are not using the extensions, then you have generic groupOfNames objects for users and roles with the dn for each user or role as member attributes, and role objects are also groupOfNames objects with user dn as member attribute.

Comment: Only membership in the (external) role is assigned in the directory. Permissions are granted to the external role within the database. Entries in the directory are linked by DN, mapping to database objects uses the corresponding CN